# How to display console output in Sonar?

Tags: logging, sonarqube

I have previously run Junit tests in Jenkins and remember seeing logging information displayed as part of the console output. Now I am running the tests in Sonar (started from Jenkins) but can't see anywhere the logging output from the Junit tests. Can you give me an advice on how to record this output in Sonar? In worst case, I know I can run the Junit tests twice - once in Jenkins to record the logging and a second time in Sonar (to record static code analysis and test coverage) but I am looking for a solution which achieves both goals in a single execution.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar does not keep the console output of tests like Jenkins does. It just keeps the stacktrace when there are test failures/errors.